# could not load file or assembly sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, sharepoint-2010, gac

I am relatively new to sharepoint 2010 and  I have the following error when I click on the a page/specific webparts

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies
```

I have checked that the dll is in my bin file with the correct version. Appreciate if anyone can help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your file to GAC (c:\windows\assembly).
If it still would not work, there might be SafeControl statement missing from web.config file.